# Llamar los valores de un diccionario con una tupla

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios

Quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar con un problema que estoy teniendo

Hace poco comencé a incursionar en python y hasta ahora todas mis dudas han tenido respuesta, sin embargo, la que no puedo responder es la que me trae aquí

El problema es el siguiente:

Deseo asignar un valor sacado de un diccionario a un tupla que ingreso por teclado
un poco del código

```
diccionario = {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, ' ': 0 }

usuario = input('ingrese una frase o palabra:\n')
transform1 = usuario.lower()
transform2 = tuple(transform1)
resultado = diccionario.get(transform2) #Aqui es donde falla todo
print(resultado)
```

Lo que yo busco es que al ingresa una frase o palabra, este código devuelva el equivalente en números basándose en mi diccionario

Seguro que es algo sencillo lo que que estoy planteando pero la verdad no encontré en ningún lado como usar las llaves de los diccionarios mediante una tupla

Gracias y disculpen la molestia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Python, las tuplas son un tipo de dato no mutable (no puedes modificar su contenido), por lo que te sugiero que uses una lista para añadir el valor correspondiente a cada letra con el método *.append()* iterando la cadena de entrada.

```
diccionario = {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, ' ': 0 }
valuesList = []

usuario = input('ingrese una frase o palabra:\n')
transform1 = usuario.lower()
for letter in transform1:
    valuesList.append(diccionario[letter])
        

print(valuesList)
```

Si obligatoriamente lo requieres dentro de una tupla, usa *tuple(valuesList)*.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, la verdad tenia una leve idea de hacer algo parecido pero bueno , no llegue a eso, gracias de nuevo